# c# xml serialize string member with specific formatter

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, linq-to-xml

I have float member, and when I serialize it to a file I'd like to have it in a specific format (for example

```
 string.Format("{0:0.00}",someFloat)
```

Can I put the formatter in the xml attribute of this member? and if so what is the exact syntax of doin it?

Comment: I don't know of if we can add formatter in XML attribute or not but please refer to this link. The second answer may help you. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404650/control-xml-serialization-format-with-a-specific-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialization used to transform data to universal readable and palatable format. Yo don't need to format when serialize. you can format it when you show in UI.
if you really need to do this, check this SO answer [Can you specify format for XmlSerialization of a datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118833/can-you-specify-format-for-xmlserialization-of-a-datetime)